# Notation for a size of a partitioning and mapping between set elements and partitions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, set-partition

Consider a infinite set of continuous numbers $A$. Now, I partition the set in N subsets $A_0, A_1, \cdots, A_N$. Thus, $A = \bigcup_{i=0}^N A_i$ and $\bigcap_{i=0}^N A_i = \emptyset$. We can say that $A = \{ A_0, A_1, \cdots, A_N\} $

I want to say 2 things about $A$, but I am not sure how to write mathematically.

1. I have a function $f: A \rightarrow \{0, 1, \cdots, N\}$ that maps $a
       \in A$ to a specified partition.
2. I want to describe $N$ by applying
   an operator to the partition e.g., $|A|$ is nice, but $|A|$ is not
   equal to $N$ but instead equal to the number of element of all partitions.

I am not sure how I can write these things.

Comment: Several questions: What is a "continuous number"?  $A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_N$ seemingly has $N+1$ subsets, yet you say $N$ subsets.  Is that a typo and do you mean $N+1$ subsets?  Typically a partition requires $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$.  This is stronger than $\bigcap_{i=0}^N A_i = \emptyset$.  Is this another typo?  Using the usual notation, usually $A \neq \{A_0, A_1, \cdots, A_N\}$ so do you actually want to have equality there, or are you just abusing notation to say that $\{A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_N\}$ is an ordered partition of $A$?

Comment: There are no continuous numbers.

Comment: @BrianMoehring You are right. I did not mean continuous numbers. I meant uncountable infinite e.g., like the reals and not the integers (but I think this doesn't change the question). Also, yes. I meant $N+1$ not $N$. I will correct the question. Finally, yes. I also meant the typical partition definition, so I require $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$. However, I do require equality. Is equality not  required for a partitioning? Additionally, the ordering doesn't necessarily matter except for the fact, I must define a mapping between elements and partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your setup (see my comment).  Here I'm assuming $\mathcal{A} = \{A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_N\}$ is a partition of $A$ with the usual notation.

In that case, it would seem you are asking for

1. $f : A \to \{0, 1, \ldots, N\}$ is defined by $a \in A_{f(a)}$ for all $a \in A$
2. $N+1 = |\mathcal{A}|$

Note that the function in (1) is well-defined using the usual definition of "partition", but not well-defined as you've defined a "partition".  As you've defined it, you would need instead to define it as something like $f(a) = \min\{i \mid a \in A_i, 0 \leq i \leq N\}$

Comment: Gotcha. For 2, I just need to define a set of sets containing all the partitions. For 1, what do you mean by $A_{f(a)}$?